# How to identify frame objects in web page of safari browser by testcomplete

Tags: vbscript, safari-extension, testcomplete

[image]I am trying to use safari(5.1.7) to work with web applications in testcomplete(10.10), I have installed safari extension also. I want to do cross browser testing  in testcomplete,I am using VB scripting language, i am using DOM object model for working with web applications, i am able to identify the  frame objects in firefox  and internet explorer but I am unable to identify the objects in frame of a web page in safari browser,can you please suggest me how to identify frame objects in webpage in safari browser by testcomplete, is there any patch needed for identifying objects in safari browser through tetscomplete?please help me....thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide details on what exactly works for other browsers and does not work for Safari. And it seems to me that the better place to ask your question is the vendor support (http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete).

Comment: i have attached the screen shots above,here In IE, the objects in  frame of a web page is displayed but in safari the frame name only displayed and frame objects are not displayed, could you please suggest me if any patch or settings are to be set,please help me

Comment: I just checked and everything works fine for me. Do you see this problem with other pages (e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_cols)?

Comment: yes,  i observed that it is worked in some of sites and not worked in some of sites(in my company sites), i thought this issue might be like in chrome.In chrome, To solve this,we are using  command line parameters(--disable-web-security and --allow-file-access-from-files) ,here for safari, which command line switches are used to work with cross origin frame sets in a web page..please help me... if any alternative to solve this..

Comment: I think that the best way to resolve this is to contact SmartBear Support.